# logic app or azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, paas

I am implementing a REST endpoint

The code it envokes

- will do a lookup to another endpoint

  based on that result
- do another call

  or
- store something in a DB

Because it is invoked by HTTP and "custom" code, I think it should be implemented as an Azure Function, however I know it could be implemented as a Logic App

I also prefer the Azure Function approach as I can develop and test it locally ( unit tests ) and have deploy-able code should we ever wish to migrate the functionality.

Is this the correct approach ?

Comment: It sounds like in your pipeline you have branching which lends itself to Logic Apps and you aren't restricted to not using both. It almost sounds like some combination of Azure functions and Logic Apps could be a good solution for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Either works. Use whatever you prefer. Both are simple enough to work with you can rearchitect if needed. Functions can be wrapped by Logic Apps easily, as well.

Comment: I am thinking now a API App might be a better

Comment: API App if you want a full Web Server, but you have to pay for it all the time
Logic App if you want a code-less experience and only pay for what you use.
Functions if you want a code based experience and only pay for what you use.
Or Functions + Logic Apps for some code, and only pay for what you use.